# Can anybody identify this plant?

Tags: houseplants, ground-cover

It's a groundcover plant, only about 10 cm tall. As you can see the leaves are bi-colour, sage greenish on the upper side and purple underneath. The leaves are sword like, and how it looks is almost like succulent (only the leave arrangement, it's not a succulent).

Comment: I think the upload of your photo didn't work out.

Comment: Please [edit] your post with photographs of the plant in question. The image uploader is the sixth button from the left (looks like a little picture frame); click on it and follow the instructions.